# percentage sign at highchart tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

got this.point.series.name

```
return this.point.series.name + '<br/>' + _self.options.prefix + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 2) + _self.options.suffix;
```

with (%) - at data table it looks correct:

**some information blablabla (%)**

at tooltip it ommit just % sign and displays:

**some information blablabla ()**

any idea what could be a reason?
I'm fresh with Highcharts so not sure where may I find a problem.
regards
pszemo

Comment: found the reason:
data-suffix='%' at code which implements data chart,
so another question is - how may I use % sign at name and as data-suffix?

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle with your code so we can have a look and see what happens? It would be very helpful.

Comment: You can edit [pointFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat) or [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and add missing %

Comment: as for now found workaround - changed data suffix from '%' into '% '
looks like data-suffix sign cannot be used at series.name string